# lapply to convert rasters to polygons using gdal_polygonizeR

Tags: r, polygon, lapply, raster, rgdal

I am using John Baumgrtner's `gdal_polygonizeR` (https://johnbaumgartner.wordpress.com/2012/07/26/getting-rasters-into-shape-from-r/) to covert rasters to polygons in R. Aside - I tried `raster` pkg `rasterToPolygons` function and it took forever; `gdal_polygonizeR` is way faster. Anyways, I have a list of 533 raster files (different extents) that I want to convert to polygons. The `gdal_polygonizeR` function works when a single list element is called, but I have tried to use it on all list elements using `lapply` and get an error message. See code below:

```
#path to folder containing all .tif raster files
dir <- "/path/to/raster/files"

#create a list of the files in the folder
files <- list.files(path = dir, pattern = ".tif$")

#use lapply to import/create list of all files in folder
rasterl_50 <- lapply(paste0(dir, files), raster)

#test gdal_polygonizeR function on single list element
gdal_polygonizeR(rasterl_50[[1]])     #works properly

#loop thru all elements in list
lapply(rasterl_50, gdal_polygonizeR)
```

Output = the first six (6) elements seem to run OK, but I get the following error msg at [[7]]:

> wfp1 <- gdal_polygonizeR(rasterl_50[[1]])
>   Creating output /var/folders/s9/pm92gdl94h18k4n6026cb8x00000gn/T//RtmpvRRvA4/file23d4dc99d8d.shp of format ESRI Shapefile.
>   0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
>   wfp2 <- gdal_polygonizeR(rasterl_50[[2]])
>   Creating output /var/folders/s9/pm92gdl94h18k4n6026cb8x00000gn/T//RtmpvRRvA4/file23d7698a853.shp of format ESRI Shapefile.
>   0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
>   wfp3 <- gdal_polygonizeR(rasterl_50[[3]])
>   Creating output /var/folders/s9/pm92gdl94h18k4n6026cb8x00000gn/T//RtmpvRRvA4/file23d30d4d703.shp of format ESRI Shapefile.
>   0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
>   wfp4 <- gdal_polygonizeR(rasterl_50[[4]])
>   Creating output /var/folders/s9/pm92gdl94h18k4n6026cb8x00000gn/T//RtmpvRRvA4/file23d24036d07.shp of format ESRI Shapefile.
>   0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
>   wfp5 <- gdal_polygonizeR(rasterl_50[[5]])
>   Creating output /var/folders/s9/pm92gdl94h18k4n6026cb8x00000gn/T//RtmpvRRvA4/file23d4683ed87.shp of format ESRI Shapefile.
>   0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
>   wfp6 <- gdal_polygonizeR(rasterl_50[[6]])
>   Creating output /var/folders/s9/pm92gdl94h18k4n6026cb8x00000gn/T//RtmpvRRvA4/file23d4e23b4d1.shp of format ESRI Shapefile.
>   0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
>   wfp7 <- gdal_polygonizeR(rasterl_50[[7]])
>   Creating output /var/folders/s9/pm92gdl94h18k4n6026cb8x00000gn/T//RtmpvRRvA4/file23d6791d108.shp of format ESRI Shapefile.
>   0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
>   Error in readOGR(dirname(outshape), layer = basename(outshape), verbose = !quiet) : 
>     no features found
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In ogrFIDs(dsn = dsn, layer = layer) :
>    Show Traceback

Rerun with Debug
 Error in readOGR(dirname(outshape), layer = basename(outshape), verbose = !quiet) : 
  no features found

### #

If anyone has ideas for a solution using `lapply` or a for loop etc., please reply. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Solution: I had to run `gdal_polygonizeR` on each individual list element, and found that several raster files in the list contained no values (this resulted from `reclassify` function applied to rasters prior). I removed these files from the list, and `lapply` worked. Here is the code:

```
#remove 'no value' elements from the list
new_rastlist <- 
rasterlist[c(-7,-14,-36,-89,-191,-310,-432,-436,-476,-493,-494,-501)]

#then try again to use lapply
polyl <- lapply(rastlist, gdal_polygonizeR)
```

UPDATE:
Even better, remove rasters with all NAs first with this:

```
batch_reclass <- function(rastlist){
  for (i in 1:length(wfrastlist)) {
    #read in raster
    r <-raster(paste0("/path/to/rasterfiles/", rastlist[i]))
    #perform the reclassifcation
    rc <- reclassify(r, rclmat)
    #write each reclass to a new file 
    if (!is.na(minValue(rc))) {
    writeRaster(rc,  filename = paste0("/path/to/new/rasterfiles/", "rc_", 
    rastlist[i]), format="GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)
  }}
}

#run the function
batch_reclass(rastlist)
```